# Web Scraping with Selenium and Beautiful Soup - converting into a CSV file

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver, export-to-csv

I need to web scrape the prices, brands and product name from a e-com site. My code right now is able to scrape the Brand and product name combined. Also the prices are combined (reduced and normal price). What do I need to change if I want to separate Brand and product name and also the reduced price with the normal price? Finally everything needs to be put into a csv file but I am also unable to write the correct code.

Below you can find my code.
Thanks a lot for your time!

```
from pathlib import Path
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

PATH = "/Users/Ziye/Desktop/Python/chromedriver"

def get_html(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    driver.get(url)
    return driver.page_source

def main ():
    url = "https://www.zalando.de/damen/?q=michael+michael+kors+taschen&p=2"
    html = get_html(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    cards = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "qMZa55 SQGpu8 iOzucJ JT3_zV DvypSJ"})
    print(len(cards))


for card in cards:
    print(card.find(class_="hPWzFB").get_text())

    print(card.find(class_="_0xLoFW u9KIT8 _7ckuOK").get_text())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use pandas here. As you are iterating through `cards`, throw the data into a dictionary (with the key being whatever you want the column name to be), then append them into a list. Construct the table from that and write to file.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

PATH = "/Users/Ziye/Desktop/Python/chromedriver"
PATH = "C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"

def get_html(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    driver.get(url)
    return driver.page_source

def main ():
    rows = []
    url = "https://www.zalando.de/damen/?q=michael+michael+kors+taschen&p=2"
    html = get_html(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    cards = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "qMZa55 SQGpu8 iOzucJ JT3_zV DvypSJ"})
    print(len(cards))


    for card in cards:
        print(card.find(class_="hPWzFB").get_text())
    
        print(card.find(class_="_0xLoFW u9KIT8 _7ckuOK").get_text())
        
        row = {'col1': card.find(class_="hPWzFB").get_text(),
               'col2': card.find(class_="_0xLoFW u9KIT8 _7ckuOK").get_text().strip()}
        
        rows.append(row)
        
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
    df[['col_2A', 'col_2B']] = df['col2'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
    df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Better Solution:**

I'm also going to offer a better/more robust solution here. The data can be fetched directly through the api. No need to use selenium.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://en.zalando.de/api/catalog/articles'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36'}
payload = {
'categories': 'women',
'limit': '84',
'offset': '0',
'query': 'michael michael kors taschen'}

jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()

total_pages = jsonData['pagination']['page_count']
per_page = len(jsonData['articles'])

rows = []
for offset in range(0,total_pages):
    if offset == 0:
        pass
    else:
        payload.update({'offset':per_page*offset})
        jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
        
    articles = jsonData['articles']
    rows += articles
    print('Page: %s of %s' %(offset+1,total_pages))
    
df = pd.json_normalize(rows)
```

**Output:** This will get you all the data, 328 rows in about 2 seconds.

```
print(df.head(5).to_string())
             sku                                        name       sizes                                                                  url_key                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             media            brand_name  is_premium                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          family_articles                                                                          flags product_group                                                                       delivery_promises price.original price.promotional  price.has_different_prices  price.has_different_original_prices  price.has_different_promotional_prices  price.has_discount_on_selected_sizes_only
0  MK151H0IH-Q11                  VOYAGER - Tote bag - black  [One Size]  michael-michael-kors-voyager-signature-tote-handbag-black-mk151h0ih-q11  [{'path': 'spp-media-p1/76f7c78f9cc63f1192a3e2c29946130f/0b46cac7883e4c7ba71dd5b14b8c3811.jpg', 'role': 'DEFAULT', 'packet_shot': False}, {'path': 'spp-media-p1/c03dbf3ac05a32b5800410422333f513/8b7a7099a3254ebca45791b1f72c34fa.jpg', 'role': 'HOVER', 'packet_shot': False}]  MICHAEL Michael Kors        True                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 [{'sku': 'MK151H0IH-Q11', 'url_key': 'michael-michael-kors-voyager-signature-tote-handbag-black-mk151h0ih-q11', 'media': [{'path': 'spp-media-p1/c9ab2b63cfe739e5bbe98e65f59bbecf/20d472ce70d24b289f4ec45672974773.jpg', 'role': 'FAMILY', 'packet_shot': True}], 'name': 'VOYAGER - Tote bag - black', 'sizes': ['One Size'], 'price': {'original': '249,95 €', 'promotional': '174,95 €', 'has_different_prices': False, 'has_different_original_prices': False, 'has_different_promotional_prices': False, 'has_discount_on_selected_sizes_only': False}, 'flags': [{'key': 'discountRate', 'value': '-30%', 'tracking_value': 'discount rate'}], 'delivery_promises': [{'key': 'plus_flag', 'label': 'Premium Delivery', 'media_key': 'plus_delivery_flag'}]}, {'sku': 'MK151H0IH-C11', 'url_key': 'michael-michael-kors-voyager-signature-tote-handbag-mk151h0ih-c11', 'media': [{'path': 'spp-media-p1/8d4ff9ca955f36259d05ac4984639516/6e08275415d349b9a6f4394c19c5f23f.jpg', 'role': 'FAMILY', 'packet_shot': True}], 'name': 'VOYAGER - Tote bag - pearl grey', 'sizes': ['One Size'], 'price': {'original': '249,95 €', 'promotional': '249,95 €', 'has_different_prices': False, 'has_different_original_prices': False, 'has_different_promotional_prices': False, 'has_discount_on_selected_sizes_only': False}, 'flags': [], 'delivery_promises': [{'key': 'plus_flag', 'label': 'Premium Delivery', 'media_key': 'plus_delivery_flag'}]}]  [{'key': 'discountRate', 'value': '-30%', 'tracking_value': 'discount rate'}]   accessoires  [{'key': 'plus_flag', 'label': 'Premium Delivery', 'media_key': 'plus_delivery_flag'}]       249,95 €          174,95 €                       False                                False                                   False                                      False
1  MK151H0E6-B11  POUCHES CHAIN POUCHETTE - Clutch - vanilla  [One Size]                           michael-michael-kors-clutch-sand-mk151h0e6-b11  [{'path': 'spp-media-p1/38b844528a8538d6abd3af70aa241cb9/b7bf5696bb51419c82a7e93ea1e11f79.jpg', 'role': 'DEFAULT', 'packet_shot': False}, {'path': 'spp-media-p1/60c65b6cad603e1b90cbb35564a8ed06/9e4560de580e49f680f6f0df8b3db0e1.jpg', 'role': 'HOVER', 'packet_shot': False}]  MICHAEL Michael Kors        True                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              [{'sku': 'MK151H0E6-B11', 'url_key': 'michael-michael-kors-clutch-sand-mk151h0e6-b11', 'media': [{'path': 'spp-media-p1/1e2e87e311d035a1b74c2cdd36025ae9/244c417b076d4845bcaeabb119051aab.jpg', 'role': 'FAMILY', 'packet_shot': True}], 'name': 'POUCHES CHAIN POUCHETTE - Clutch - vanilla', 'sizes': ['One Size'], 'price': {'original': '124,95 €', 'promotional': '124,95 €', 'has_different_prices': False, 'has_different_original_prices': False, 'has_different_promotional_prices': False, 'has_discount_on_selected_sizes_only': False}, 'flags': [], 'delivery_promises': [{'key': 'plus_flag', 'label': 'Premium Delivery', 'media_key': 'plus_delivery_flag'}]}, {'sku': 'MK151H0E6-O11', 'url_key': 'michael-michael-kors-clutch-brown-mk151h0e6-o11', 'media': [{'path': 'spp-media-p1/9b5386b8220e3e808372d90404028a3a/948b37c4fb574c64acfc52ee05e4a7f5.jpg', 'role': 'FAMILY', 'packet_shot': True}], 'name': 'POUCHES CHAIN POUCHETTE - Clutch - brown', 'sizes': ['One Size'], 'price': {'original': '124,95 €', 'promotional': '124,95 €', 'has_different_prices': False, 'has_different_original_prices': False, 'has_different_promotional_prices': False, 'has_discount_on_selected_sizes_only': False}, 'flags': [], 'delivery_promises': [{'key': 'plus_flag', 'label': 'Premium Delivery', 'media_key': 'plus_delivery_flag'}]}]                                                                             []   accessoires  [{'key': 'plus_flag', 'label': 'Premium Delivery', 'media_key': 'plus_delivery_flag'}]       124,95 €          124,95 €                       False                                False                                   False                                      False
2  MK151H0ST-O11       SULLIVAN TOTE - Handbag - brown/acorn  [One Size]      michael-michael-kors-sullivan-tote-handbag-brownacorn-mk151h0st-o11   [{'path': 'spp-media-p1/346d861e13623b8a8b43d0d3fcbad325/60cc8931e3ce4c78a37942ddaf046193.jpg', 'role': 'DEFAULT', 'packet_shot': True}, {'path': 'spp-media-p1/0df2c6e3cd033641b05128cb36c4f687/2a2a3d47a0de46faa64fe2981ae3b9d9.jpg', 'role': 'HOVER', 'packet_shot': False}]  MICHAEL Michael Kors        True                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             [{'sku': 'MK151H0ST-O11', 'url_key': 'michael-michael-kors-sullivan-tote-handbag-brownacorn-mk151h0st-o11', 'media': [{'path': 'spp-media-p1/346d861e13623b8a8b43d0d3fcbad325/60cc8931e3ce4c78a37942ddaf046193.jpg', 'role': 'FAMILY', 'packet_shot': True}], 'name': 'SULLIVAN TOTE - Handbag - brown/acorn', 'sizes': ['One Size'], 'price': {'original': '274,95 €', 'promotional': '274,95 €', 'has_different_prices': False, 'has_different_original_prices': False, 'has_different_promotional_prices': False, 'has_discount_on_selected_sizes_only': False}, 'flags': [], 'delivery_promises': [{'key': 'plus_flag', 'label': 'Premium Delivery', 'media_key': 'plus_delivery_flag'}]}, {'sku': 'MK151H0ST-O12', 'url_key': 'michael-michael-kors-sullivan-tote-handbag-brownblack-mk151h0st-o12', 'media': [{'path': 'spp-media-p1/809deafa120433bba6b979fda5deaf36/0dd2ca0f586445ed94d54300209c2765.jpg', 'role': 'FAMILY', 'packet_shot': True}], 'name': 'SULLIVAN TOTE - Handbag - brown/black', 'sizes': ['One Size'], 'price': {'original': '274,95 €', 'promotional': '274,95 €', 'has_different_prices': False, 'has_different_original_prices': False, 'has_different_promotional_prices': False, 'has_discount_on_selected_sizes_only': False}, 'flags': [], 'delivery_promises': [{'key': 'plus_flag', 'label': 'Premium Delivery', 'media_key': 'plus_delivery_flag'}]}]                                                                             []   accessoires  [{'key': 'plus_flag', 'label': 'Premium Delivery', 'media_key': 'plus_delivery_flag'}]       274,95 €          274,95 €                       False                                False                                   False                                      False
3  MK151H0E6-O11    POUCHES CHAIN POUCHETTE - Clutch - brown  [One Size]                          michael-michael-kors-clutch-brown-mk151h0e6-o11  [{'path': 'spp-media-p1/1e96df7e492b39aebda591a3792ef1e9/afe01fccd4864bc1bd2c0df17c8bf0fd.jpg', 'role': 'DEFAULT', 'packet_shot': False}, {'path': 'spp-media-p1/9b699c2aa1b535158848cc44c274520f/60aab3e3c4bf49c6b4ee2e4df3db5aeb.jpg', 'role': 'HOVER', 'packet_shot': False}]  MICHAEL Michael Kors        True                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              [{'sku': 'MK151H0E6-O11', 'url_key': 'michael-michael-kors-clutch-brown-mk151h0e6-o11', 'media': [{'path': 'spp-media-p1/9b5386b8220e3e808372d90404028a3a/948b37c4fb574c64acfc52ee05e4a7f5.jpg', 'role': 'FAMILY', 'packet_shot': True}], 'name': 'POUCHES CHAIN POUCHETTE - Clutch - brown', 'sizes': ['One Size'], 'price': {'original': '124,95 €', 'promotional': '124,95 €', 'has_different_prices': False, 'has_different_original_prices': False, 'has_different_promotional_prices': False, 'has_discount_on_selected_sizes_only': False}, 'flags': [], 'delivery_promises': [{'key': 'plus_flag', 'label': 'Premium Delivery', 'media_key': 'plus_delivery_flag'}]}, {'sku': 'MK151H0E6-B11', 'url_key': 'michael-michael-kors-clutch-sand-mk151h0e6-b11', 'media': [{'path': 'spp-media-p1/1e2e87e311d035a1b74c2cdd36025ae9/244c417b076d4845bcaeabb119051aab.jpg', 'role': 'FAMILY', 'packet_shot': True}], 'name': 'POUCHES CHAIN POUCHETTE - Clutch - vanilla', 'sizes': ['One Size'], 'price': {'original': '124,95 €', 'promotional': '124,95 €', 'has_different_prices': False, 'has_different_original_prices': False, 'has_different_promotional_prices': False, 'has_discount_on_selected_sizes_only': False}, 'flags': [], 'delivery_promises': [{'key': 'plus_flag', 'label': 'Premium Delivery', 'media_key': 'plus_delivery_flag'}]}]                                                                             []   accessoires  [{'key': 'plus_flag', 'label': 'Premium Delivery', 'media_key': 'plus_delivery_flag'}]       124,95 €          124,95 €                       False                                False                                   False                                      False
4  MK151H0SP-Q11          MAXINE MESSENGER - Handbag - black  [One Size]      michael-michael-kors-maxinesm-messenger-handbag-black-mk151h0sp-q11  [{'path': 'spp-media-p1/43f07a4a9ceb3c6ca8195e0014e13918/cdfcd04d7f51427e8f9a0eca0caba2f9.jpg', 'role': 'DEFAULT', 'packet_shot': False}, {'path': 'spp-media-p1/4fa0d8348a683e569c4b4fb0ab8bcc31/5c9f9d9038e0496e910b3f564feab32e.jpg', 'role': 'HOVER', 'packet_shot': False}]  MICHAEL Michael Kors        True  [{'sku': 'MK151H0SP-Q11', 'url_key': 'michael-michael-kors-maxinesm-messenger-handbag-black-mk151h0sp-q11', 'media': [{'path': 'spp-media-p1/7075bf593ad13cba80d4f8e82dd4aa3f/fcfdad585bbc4339b47577f37480fb00.jpg', 'role': 'FAMILY', 'packet_shot': True}], 'name': 'MAXINE MESSENGER - Handbag - black', 'sizes': ['One Size'], 'price': {'original': '294,95 €', 'promotional': '206,95 €', 'has_different_prices': False, 'has_different_original_prices': False, 'has_different_promotional_prices': False, 'has_discount_on_selected_sizes_only': False}, 'flags': [{'key': 'discountRate', 'value': '-30%', 'tracking_value': 'discount rate'}], 'delivery_promises': [{'key': 'plus_flag', 'label': 'Premium Delivery', 'media_key': 'plus_delivery_flag'}]}, {'sku': 'MK151H0SP-A11', 'url_key': 'michael-michael-kors-maxine-messenger-handbag-optic-white-mk151h0sp-a11', 'media': [{'path': 'spp-media-p1/89615d7cf5ae362db1dfb18199ebac91/9f98d12b9fe14c70b0519045cac290c2.jpg', 'role': 'FAMILY', 'packet_shot': True}], 'name': 'MAXINE MESSENGER - Handbag - optic white', 'sizes': ['One Size'], 'price': {'original': '294,95 €', 'promotional': '205,95 €', 'has_different_prices': False, 'has_different_original_prices': False, 'has_different_promotional_prices': False, 'has_discount_on_selected_sizes_only': False}, 'flags': [{'key': 'discountRate', 'value': '-30%', 'tracking_value': 'discount rate'}], 'delivery_promises': [{'key': 'plus_flag', 'label': 'Premium Delivery', 'media_key': 'plus_delivery_flag'}]}, {'sku': 'MK151H0SP-J11', 'url_key': 'michael-michael-kors-messenger-handbag-soft-pink-mk151h0sp-j11', 'media': [{'path': 'spp-media-p1/d3b5ffc2e251360291ece80b44f1a2e0/b6512dbb6a7749c189a6d33177f922df.jpg', 'role': 'FAMILY', 'packet_shot': True}], 'name': 'MAXINE MESSENGER - Handbag - soft pink', 'sizes': ['One Size'], 'price': {'original': '294,95 €', 'promotional': '294,95 €', 'has_different_prices': False, 'has_different_original_prices': False, 'has_different_promotional_prices': False, 'has_discount_on_selected_sizes_only': False}, 'flags': [], 'delivery_promises': [{'key': 'plus_flag', 'label': 'Premium Delivery', 'media_key': 'plus_delivery_flag'}]}, {'sku': 'MK151H0SP-B11', 'url_key': 'michael-michael-kors-messenger-handbag-acorn-mk151h0sp-b11', 'media': [{'path': 'spp-media-p1/7e96e989cf643a2f957b6f6640056837/cf772fdbd7f44e929bc8af90d750ae94.jpg', 'role': 'FAMILY', 'packet_shot': True}], 'name': 'MAXINE MESSENGER - Handbag - acorn', 'sizes': ['One Size'], 'price': {'original': '294,95 €', 'promotional': '294,95 €', 'has_different_prices': False, 'has_different_original_prices': False, 'has_different_promotional_prices': False, 'has_discount_on_selected_sizes_only': False}, 'flags': [], 'delivery_promises': [{'key': 'plus_flag', 'label': 'Premium Delivery', 'media_key': 'plus_delivery_flag'}]}, {'sku': 'MK151H0SP-K11', 'url_key': 'michael-michael-kors-maxinesm-messenger-handbag-navy-mk151h0sp-k11', 'media': [{'path': 'spp-media-p1/72638ccdea433a7188c9f61582433921/17e1c0f4837146d28d79cb889058ddef.jpg', 'role': 'FAMILY', 'packet_shot': False}], 'name': 'MAXINE MESSENGER - Handbag - navy', 'sizes': ['One Size'], 'price': {'original': '294,95 €', 'promotional': '205,95 €', 'has_different_prices': False, 'has_different_original_prices': False, 'has_different_promotional_prices': False, 'has_discount_on_selected_sizes_only': False}, 'flags': [{'key': 'discountRate', 'value': '-30%', 'tracking_value': 'discount rate'}], 'delivery_promises': [{'key': 'plus_flag', 'label': 'Premium Delivery', 'media_key': 'plus_delivery_flag'}]}]  [{'key': 'discountRate', 'value': '-30%', 'tracking_value': 'discount rate'}]   accessoires  [{'key': 'plus_flag', 'label': 'Premium Delivery', 'media_key': 'plus_delivery_flag'}]       294,95 €          206,95 €                       False                                False                                   False                                      False
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped a lot. I was able to create a csv. However I am still unable to get the prices separated. If you go to the link you will see sometimes two different prices per product (one is reduced and one is the normal price). How can I print the prices separately into two rows in the csv?

Comment: Won’t be able to look at it today, but I’ll fix that for you tomorrow morning.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I appreciate that :)

Comment: Hello! Did you had time to look through it by any chance?

Comment: @ZiYe, also look at my alternate solution as it's better/more efficient implemantation(IMO)

Comment: I somehow get this error code
KeyError: 'col2'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Ziye/Desktop/Python/Z copy 2.py", line 37, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/Ziye/Desktop/Python/Z copy 2.py", line 33, in main
    df[['col_2A', 'col_2B']] = df['col2'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2980, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

Comment: what version of pandas you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231741/discussion-between-zi-ye-and-chitown88).

Comment: Hello, I was trying to use this link with the selenium code but somehow it does not work, does it work with you?

Link: https://www.zalando.de/damen/?q=love+moschino+kleider

Comment: thats because the data is generated by js. The htnl likely doesnt have the the particlar class. Use the second option I provided, and chage the query parameter to `'love moschino kleider'`